# SQL Variable Declaration Error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am able to connect to a SQL Server 2012 instance using (Oracle) SQL developer.

I a trying to create some dynamic SQL to query the database.

However, when I run the SQL statement:

```
DECLARE @SQLquery as NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
```

then I get the following error message:

> Error starting at line : 2 in command -
>   DECLARE @SQLquery as NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
>   Error report -
>   Invalid JDBC escape syntax at line position 24 '=' character expected.`

Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Comment: Doggone it!

It seems that 'SQL Developer does allow you to run single T-SQL commands against SQL Server':

https://community.oracle.com/thread/1009263

Comment: Follow the yellow brick [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/sql-server-connection-viewlet-swf-089886.html)

Answer (score -1):

First declare and then set value

```
DECLARE @SQLquery as NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQLquery=''
```